# Idrac 7 instance won't connect virtual media

Tags: drac

I have a remote ubuntu server that I just tried to upgrade inplace and failed.  So I fired up iDRAC to rebuild it from scratch but I can not attach a virtual ISO.  I get a popup saying "virtual media is connecting..." which sits there for ever.

I have verified this works fine with other more or less identical servers running the same version of iDRAC.  I have also verified that some other things on that machine that iDRAC pops up a file window for also work.

Under normal circumstances I would go down stairs with the ISO on a UBS stick and ask one of the datacenter team to pop it into the server when they next visit the datacenter but (as of today) we are in a national (NZ) lockdown so that option isn't available.

Oh yes, I have also cycled the power via iDRAC and looked for some way to reset IDRAC itself to no avail.

Does anyone have any ideas what might cause iDRAC to behave like this? Or any other way of getting this thing going without physical access to the machine?

Answer (score 0):

I have seen problems if USB mounting of devices is disabled in the Bios. Sometimes toggling the bios setting each way will reset it if it is allowed in the bios and just not working. Boot order can also prevent it from booting the virtual media. Make sure that virtual CD and physical CD are listed first before hard drives and raid controller.

The idrac itself can be restarted in the maintenance menu.

Also are you doing the mount from the console session or the server interface? The console session ones are only active when the console is open.

Comment: one point the reset instructions are for idrac 9.  For idrac 8 and below there is a 'reset' entry on the overview page under 'Quick Launch Tasks'. my browser it was just off the bottom of the screen.  Still waiting for the reset!

Answer (score 0):

I have a dell R720 with iDRAC7 which suddenly got this issue where it would just get stuck on "virtual media is connecting...". Since I was using he HTML interface, clearing the browser cache solved this for me.